# Selecting all the from a table in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using this procedure to create a `GUID` number when reading a table.

The stored procedure works correctly, but displays only two column, `id` and `EventId`.

I need to display all the other columns of `dbo.ASFC_App_Timetable` beyond `id` and `EventId`.

Other columns are `EventTitle` and `EventNote` for example.

Are you able to provide me a sample of code for solving this issue?

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE SPROCGetAllEventsForStudent
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT convert(uniqueidentifier,
               stuff('62799568-6EF2-4C95-84E7-4953A6959C99',1,len(rn),convert(varchar,rn))) id,
               T.EventId
        FROM ( 
          select x.EventId,  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by x.EventId) rn
          FROM dbo.ASFC_App_Timetable as x ) T
    END
```

At the moment is displays.. I need to display the other columns, too:

```
22799568-6EF2-4C95-84E7-4953A6959C99    AB-TT-E1-2/TU12
32799568-6EF2-4C95-84E7-4953A6959C99    PU-A2-2 -Z/CL12
42799568-6EF2-4C95-84E7-4953A6959C99    PU-A2-2 -Z/CL12
52799568-6EF2-4C95-84E7-4953A6959C99    PU-A2-2 -Z/CL12
62799568-6EF2-4C95-84E7-4953A6959C99    PU-A2-2 -Z/CL12
72799568-6EF2-4C95-84E7-4953A6959C99    PU-A2-2 -Z/CL12
82799568-6EF2-4C95-84E7-4953A6959C99    PU-A2-2 -Z/CL12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why can't you add the other columns in the subquery?

```
SELECT convert(uniqueidentifier,
       stuff('62799568-6EF2-4C95-84E7-4953A6959C99',1,len(rn),convert(varchar,rn))) id,
       T.EventId, 
       T.EventTitle , 
       T.EventNote
FROM 
    ( 
        select  x.EventId, 
                x.EventTitle , 
                x.EventNote, 
                ROW_NUMBER() over (order by x.EventId) rn
        FROM    dbo.ASFC_App_Timetable as x 
    ) T
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this does work.

```
SELECT EventTitle,
       EventNote,
       convert(uniqueidentifier,
       stuff('62799568-6EF2-4C95-84E7-4953A6959C99',1,len(rn),convert(varchar,rn))) id,
       T.EventId
FROM ( 
         select x.EventId,
              EventTitle,
              EventNote,
              ROW_NUMBER() over (order by x.EventId) rn
         FROM dbo.ASFC_App_Timetable as x
     ) T
```

Why you don't use `NEWID()` to generate `GUID`?

```
SELECT NEWID() Id
      EventId,
      EventTitle,
      EventNote
 FROM dbo.ASFC_App_Timetabl
```

Comment: Hi, could you please post a sample with NEW_ID version? I Would really appreciate it

Comment: Hi thanks for your version with NEWID() but it generate a new GUID every time I run the SPROC.. In my original SPROC the GUID is not changing.. thanks for your answer